# How to collect values from response body of all the requests in a array using postman

Tags: javascript, postman

```
response body1
id:56566

response  body2
id :67627

var ar=[];

tests in request1:
var ID = JSON.parse(responseBody);
ar[0]=ID.request_id;
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("ArrayObj",JSON.stringify(ar));

tests in request2:
var ID = JSON.parse(responseBody);
ar[1]=ID.request_id;
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("ArrayObj",JSON.stringify(ar));
```

Now I want `ar` variable having array of id values declared in environment variable. But for every request, array values are stored only for that request getting `ar` value as [null,67627] instead I want as [56566,67627]

Comment: Hi there, I've added the [tag:js] tag to your question. (This will increase your chances of getting answers quicker.) If you think it was a mistake, feel free to revert the edit.

Comment: Your question is really difficult to follow, is this from the same response body? Can you add the actual full response to the question.

Comment: @Danny Dainton No.They are different response bodies (response1 and response2).Am getting the data(id')  from different response bodies and storing them in an array set as environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are refreshing your variable in your second request, so you basically overwrite it with `[null, 67627]`

In order to make this work, you need to get the variable first in your second request, add the new value to the array and set it back to the environment:

Request 1:

```
var ar = [];
ar[0] = "abc";
pm.environment.set("ArrayObj", ar);
```

Request 2:

```
var x = pm.environment.get("ArrayObj");
x[1] = "xyz";
pm.environment.set("ArrayObj", x);
```

In your environment you'll see:

```
ArrayObj       abc,xyz
```